# Chrome Redraw Issue

Tags: nvidia, google-chrome, chromium

When I am using Chrome the window will not redraw until I change focus to something else and then click back onto Chrome

I am using 2 monitors but it does not matter which monitor Chrome is on I am still faced with the same problem.

This problem occurs with everything just simply checking email is extremely frustrating, but I have no problems with Firefox, so I have to assume the problem is with some basic setting in Chrome. Normally I would say to hell with Chrome but I have a testing site that does not work correctly with Firefox so I have to use Chrome.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Graphics: GeForce 7300 LE/PCIe/SSE2
Google Chrome version 40.0.2214.111